# Swift 3 / Firebase: Encrypt string (password) for non-user object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, encryption, password-protection

I'm attempting to implement a way to "whitelist" users from a folder. i.e. User A creates the folder and a password for it. User B tries to access the folder, but the folder requires a password.

How might this work in Swift 3, with storing the password for the folder in a Firebase database? I have been having a tough time trying to find good encryption/decryption methods for this purpose.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    handleSelectRowAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)
}

func promptUserForPassword() -> String {

    //code for getting user entered password
}

func presentPasswordProtectedInformation() {

    //code for presenting password protected view controller
}

func handleSelectRowAtIndex(index: Int) {

    if (allData[index]["requiresPassword"].requiresPassword) {

        let enteredPassword = promptUserForPassword()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(allData[index]["id"])

        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let inputData = inputData()

                inputData["requiresPassword"] = dictionary["requiresPassword"]

                // I am thinking dictionary["password"] must be encrypted?
                inputData["password"] = dictionary["password"]

                if (enteredPassword == inputData["password"]) {

                    presentPasswordProtectedInformation()

                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

This is a general idea of what I'm after. This is not a current implementation I have because I am not sure of the correct way to do it. I am under a heavy assumption that passwords of this manner should not be stored in plain text and so I am looking for a safer solution.

Comment: This is a very vague question. How are you defining a 'folder'? How is a password applied? Do you have some code to demonstrate what you are doing? What needs to be encrypted and why? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I updated the post to provide an example of what I'm looking for. I apologize if it is not yet precise enough, for I do not have a working solution for what I'm after, so it's difficult to fully capture what my difficulty entails. Hopefully the example provided explains it at least a little better.

Comment: You are correct in that passwords should not be stored in as text. Encrypting them is a workable solution, however, not ideal. A better approach would be to leverage [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to allow/deny access to different nodes within Firebase. For example, user_a creates a 'folder' and wants to allow user_b and user_c to access it but not user_d. user_a can store the uid's of user_b and user_c in a node that only they have access to, and Firebase Rules would only allow users listed in that node to access the folder.

Comment: I had thought of a whitelist/blacklist solution, but for the project ideally one user would be able to give out the password instead of having to manually add users in order to grant them access.